# Declare syntax error in MYSQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How can I declare and set a variable in my `MYSQL WORKBENCH` in a stored procedure?

It gives a syntax error like `unexpected Declare_sym` at the first line with a cross sign.

I am using the following code for it:

```
Declare StartDate datetime

set StartDate = '2013-07-01';
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some googling, I got my answer.

A `Declare` statement must be in between `Begin` and `End` statement.  Additionally, it must be the first statement after the `Begin` statement.

I got the answer from [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html) wonderful site.