# MySQL Trigger IF syntax error

Tags: mysql, triggers, syntax-error, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I was creating some triggers (using MySQL Workbench), and got an error regarding the if statement in one of them. Here it is:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `mydatabase`.`transactions_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `transactions` FOR EACH ROW
begin

if (old.idUser != new.idUser) then
    signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = "Can't change transactions' initiator.";
end if;
declare oldAmountTokens integer;
SET @oldAmountTokens = (SELECT tokens from offers WHERE idoffer = old.idOffer);
declare newAmountTokens integer;
SET @newAmountTokens = (SELECT tokens from offers WHERE idoffer = new.idOffer);
declare diff integer;
SET @diff = @newAmountTokens - @oldAmountTokens;
UPDATE users SET tokens = users.tokens + @diff WHERE idUser = new.idUser;
end
```

MySQL Workbench tells me

`"missing 'end'" at line 6` (where the 'end if;' is),

and phpMyAdmin tells me

```
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5".
```

I'm really stuck on this, so I'd be really happy if someone could help me, I've searched for the IF syntax on the web, but I don't see anything wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, problem solved.

First, I needed to use delimiters to avoid the error near `end if;`.

For the next error, MySQL requires `declare` statements to be put next to the begin, thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759544/declare-syntax-error-in-mysql-workbench) I found the answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger code looks okay to me, although I am removing the single quote after `transactions`.  Do you have `delimiter` statements?

```
delimiter //

CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `mydatabase`.`transactions_AFTER_UPDATE`
    AFTER UPDATE ON `transactions` FOR EACH ROW
begin
    if (old.idUser <> new.idUser) then
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = "Can't change transactions  initiator.";
    end if;
    declare @oldAmountTokens integer;
    SET @oldAmountTokens = (SELECT tokens from offers WHERE idoffer = old.idOffer);
    declare @newAmountTokens integer;
    SET @newAmountTokens = (SELECT tokens from offers WHERE idoffer = new.idOffer);
    declare @diff integer;
    SET @diff = @newAmountTokens - @oldAmountTokens;
    UPDATE users SET tokens = users.tokens + @diff WHERE idUser = new.idUser;
end//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks, it went a bit further, but not very far unfortunately.
I've got a new error : `Syntax error near 'declare oldAmountTokens integer;
    SET @oldAmountTokens = (SELECT tokens from' at line 7`